# Получение геолокации от 3G модема

Tags: c#, геолокация, 3g

Как получить данные по геолокации от 3G модема?
Браузер определяет местоположение, причем довольно точно, а как самому что-нибудь запрограммировать?

Желательно увидеть пример какого-нибудь кода.

Модем Yota.
Система Win7 x64.

Comment: чтобы получить координаты, в браузере, в javascript пишете: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { alert(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude); });`

Comment: Это я знаю. Мне интересно есть ли в C# что нибудь подобное

Comment: если без браузера, то в Windows есть Location API, и Windows.Devices.Geolocation namespace. пример для Windows 8.1 тут https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Geolocation-2483de66

Comment: если API на Win7 недоступно, то данные в программе на C# можно получить из браузера

Comment: Подскажите, как получить данные из браузера. На Win7 насколько я знаю нет этого api.

Comment: _"На Win7 насколько я знаю нет этого api."_ -- на Win7 есть System.Device, так что браузер использовать не нужно

Comment: пример для браузера - [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435585/c-sharp-desktop-application-doesnt-share-my-physical-location)

Answer (score 1):

В Windows 7 для определения координат можно использовать Sensor API

```
// #r "System.Device"    
using System.Device.Location;
using System.Threading;

var w = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
var ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
w.TryStart(false, ts);
Thread.Sleep(ts);
Console.WriteLine(w.Position.Location);      // если будет Unknown, то надо увеличить ts
```

Работает, если в настройках Windows разрешено определять координаты.

Comment: У меня System.Device не найдено. Версия VS - 2010.

Comment: @Vladimir а версия .NET какая? в msdn: "В Windows 7 все классы System.Device.Location являются полнофункциональными, если поставщик расположения установлен и может определить расположение на компьютере." https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.device.location(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Спасибо, с классами разобрался. Но у меня почему то всегда выводит Unknown, даже если таймаут ставлю секунд 10-15. В настройках Windows вроде геолокация включена, но датчиков местоположения не определено.

Comment: _"всегда выводит Unknown"_ -- в настройках Windows надо включить разрешение определять координаты.

Comment: Сама суть моей проблемы в следующем. У меня есть обычный 3G модем, который теоретически может передать какие то данные о координатах, так как браузер их получает. Но задача состоит в том, чтобы получить эти координаты в приложении WinForms на C#, без запуска самого браузера.
Модем не определен системой как датчик местоположения, но браузер все равно каким то образом определяет координаты.

Comment: _"браузер все равно каким то образом определяет координаты."_ -- скорее всего браузер получает данные у Windows минуя настройки. надо смотреть настройки.  а браузер точные координаты выдает?

Comment: Да, точные. А где посмотреть настройки можно? В разделе Панель управления - Датчики расположения...?